# Is it possible to get statistics for individual executions in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Lets say an action in a web application causes the same database query to be executed 6 times.

If I want to find out the start time of the 6 queries and how long they took in each case, is there a way to do this from the Oracle database? Or am I missing some configurations?

I have checked v$sql but my experimentation suggests that it does not record details of individual executions.

Comment: Generate AWR report and analyze.

Comment: @LalitKumarB AWR aggregates data per query, not per query execution AFAIK.  Although in practice that should be enough information and there's very rarely a need to track individual query executions.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few option for this.
1) You can user *LOGON TRIGGER* for enable tracing

```
create or replace trigger traceme after logon on database
begin
  for tr in (
    select * from (
    select sid,serial# serial
    from v$session
    where username = user /* put here your program name or machine name, check v$session view for detail */
    order by logon_time desc
    ) where rownum < 2
  ) loop
    dbms_system.set_ev(tr.sid,tr.serial,10046,8,'');
  end loop;
end;
/
```

After you run your session find a trace files and analyze it with TKPROFF/ORASRP etc...
Another one, use ASH (not AWR!!!) report!

If you do not have installed dbconsole or OEM you can use pretty good Oracle SQLDevleoper for this :

[image]